# Can a phone respond with some data to a FCM message?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't seem to find any option for a phone to reply with a response to the caller via FCM. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Upstream Mesaaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#upstream). Note that you'd need an XMPP server protocol instead of the normal HTTP server protocol for sending Downstream messages.